# Force resort of Android appcompat `SortedList`?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-appcompat

I have a [`SortedList`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/util/SortedList.html) being displayed in a `RecyclerView` by my `RecyclerView.Adapter`.

I use 2 custom `Comparator` instances from withing the `SortedListAdapterCallback.compare()` method to either sort A-Z or Z-A.

```
static class A2Z implements Comparator<Item> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Item t0, Item t1) {
        return t0.mText.compareTo(t1.mText);
    }
}
static class Z2A extends A2Z {
    @Override
    public int compare(Item t0, Item t1) {
        return -1 * super.compare(t0, t1);
    }
}
```

`Item` simply contains a single `String mText;`

---

I use my comparators in the `SortedListAdapterCallback.compare()` method:

```
private Comparator<Item> a2z = new A2Z();
private Comparator<Item> z2a = new Z2A();
private Comparator<Item> comparator = z2a;

        @Override
        public int compare(Item t0, Item t1) {
            return comparator.compare(t0, t1);
        }
```

---

I change the comparators on a button press. The list on screen does not update.

After logging values in the various methods, I can tell that the list itself is not updating. Notifying the adapter of changes simply redraws the old list, without resorting it.

So how do I **force the underlying `SortedList` to resort** all the items?

Perhaps it is best to just create a new `Adapter` each time, as in this question:

- [RecyclerView change data set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26635841/recyclerview-change-data-set)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SortedList` does not have functionality to resort itself - each instance only has a single sort order.

Went with creating a new adapter for each resort, as per [Yigit's answer to the above referenced question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26645164/383414):

> If you have stable ids in your adapter, you can get pretty good
>   results (animations) if you create a new array containing the filtered
>   items and call
>
> ```
> recyclerView.swapAdapter(newAdapter, false);
> ```
>
> Using swapAdapter hints RecyclerView that it can re-use view holders.
>   (vs in setAdapter, it has to recycle all views and re-create because
>   it does not know that the new adapter has the same ViewHolder set with
>   the old adapter).

Answer (score 0):

Use a switch statement inside the compare method with a local control flag (an enum is a good idea).

After changing the switch flag, call sortedList.replaceAll.

```
@Override
        public int compare(PmpRole pmpRoleA, PmpRole pmpRoleB) {

            switch (mSorter){
                case IDX:
                    return pmpRoleA.getIdx().compareTo(pmpRoleB.getIdx());
                case TITLE:
                    return pmpRoleA.getTitleIdx().compareTo(pmpRoleB.getTitleIdx());
                case ID_IDX:
                    return pmpRoleA.getIdIdx().compareTo(pmpRoleB.getIdIdx());

            }
            return -1;
        }


public void setSorter(Sorter sorter){
        mSorter = sorter;
        mPmpRoleSortedList.replaceAll(mPmpRoles);
    }
```

Maintains animation functionality etc.