# my recyclerview adapter is changed using (notifyItemRangeInserted) but recyclerview never changed

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

[set data for `RecyclerView` [arraylist]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zfcg4.png)

[`OnScrollChangeListener` and where I want to update `RecyclerView`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rRVPX.png)

The above code shows the process in which i add the `RecyclerView`.

The problem when the `RecyclerView` reaches the bottom I would like it to load and update the data. Everything works fine and the `RecyclerViewAdapter` is updated and take the new items but problem is the `RecyclerView` doesn't change 
why?

I really search a lot but nothing is work, thank you

Comment: try to put code in question itself

Comment: i put the code in the 2 link above, thanks for comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

recyclerView.swapAdapter(adapter, false); 
use it after adapter updated
this solve my problem when check this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/26645164/6246772