# Kotlin RecyclerView no adapter attached skipping layout

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I don't know what the problem is but same code works fine in java
Here is my adapter class:

```
class MainAdapter(private val context: Context, private val firebaseVisionlabel: ArrayList<FirebaseVisionLabel>)  : RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomViewHolder>()  {

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return firebaseVisionlabel.size
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(p0: ViewGroup, p1: Int): CustomViewHolder {
    val v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_items,p0,false)
    return  CustomViewHolder(v)
}
override fun onBindViewHolder(p0: CustomViewHolder, p1: Int) {
    val firebaseVisionLabel = firebaseVisionlabel?.get(p1)
    val label = firebaseVisionLabel?.label
    val confidence =firebaseVisionLabel?.confidence.toString()
    p0.itemView.textView.text = label
    p0.itemView.confidence.text = confidence
}
```

}
class CustomViewHolder(v:View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(v)

MainActivity: (Global declaration)

```
var fileUri: Uri? = null
var TAG = "MainActivity"
var firebaseVisionLabels : ArrayList<FirebaseVisionLabel>? = null
```

In onCreate :

```
rec_view.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
rec_view.setHasFixedSize(true)
```

Button :

```
detect_button.setOnClickListener{
            imageRecognition()

        }
```

Function :

```
 private fun imageRecognition() {

        var bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.contentResolver, fileUri)
        var  image = FirebaseVisionImage.fromBitmap(bitmap)
        val labeler = FirebaseVision.getInstance().visionLabelDetector
        labeler.detectInImage(image)
                .addOnSuccessListener { labels ->
                    for (label in labels) {
                        val text = label.label
                        val entityId = label.entityId
                        val confidence = label.confidence

                        Log.d("TAG", "$text $confidence") //logcat works

                        firebaseVisionLabels?.add(label)
                        //Main problem??
                        rec_view.adapter = firebaseVisionLabels?.let { MainAdapter(this, it) }
                    }
                }.addOnFailureListener { e ->
                    // Task failed with an exception
                    // ...
                    detect_button.isEnabled = true
                    Log.d(TAG,e.toString())
                }

}
```

Logcat prints the expected outputs but I don't know what the problem is in recyclerview. I don't want to put bunch of camera and gallery intents codes, they works fine. Thanks for helping.

Comment: Where's the call to notifyDataSetChanged? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26635841/recyclerview-change-data-set

Answer (score 0):

I solved by changing RecyclerView to BaseAdapter and the parameter to ArrayList. I guess RecyclerView can work same with the Basedapter by changing the parameter `private val firebaseVisionlabel: ArrayList<FirebaseVisionLabel> to  private val labeltext : ArrayList<String>` I think it is a bug between FirebaseVisionLabel and Kotlin
Modified part for MainActivity :

```
 for (label in labels) {
                        for(i in 1..1){
                            val text = label.label
                            val entityId = label.entityId
                            val confidence = label.confidence
                            new_list.add(text)

                        }
                        list_view.adapter =MainAdapter(this,new_list)
```